# fixing a benchmark comparing slim.js and react.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have written a benchmark that compares my library with react.js in terms of performance. the link is available here 
https://plnkr.co/edit/UlrfL6ocFdHjAegsS6wp?p=preview

But my guess is that I'm missing something, it cannot be that react is so slow. Only 10K items it should not take so long to render. Please review and help with the benchmark code for react.

10x.

```
Slim.tag('benchmark-tester', class extends Slim)...
```

Comment: btw - open chrome dev tools to see the timing function on the console

Comment: These micro-benchmarks are generally not very accurate but it seems like you are using the in browser JSX transformer which is very slow. I also am not sure if you are using the production version of react based on the file you linked, it might not be. Finally, I'm not sure what your benchmark is actually measuring - it looks like you are timing startBenchmark but setState is asynchronous so that time won't really be included, and render also will happen outside of the timing window.

Comment: That's what I'm testing. The array builds up AFTER the dom element is ready. It adds one item at a time.